# When are {} needed to surround a string in a keyval pair

Tags: key-value

I am using the package `kvoptions` and declaring various `stringoption`'s.
When do you need to embrace a string value when calling your package/class?

E.g.
In mypackage:

```
\DeclareStringOption[defaultval]{abc}[defaultval]
```

In calling class:

```
\usepackage[abc=someval]{mypackage}
```

When are braces needed around `someval`, i.e. `abc={someval}`

Comment: You surely need braces when the option contains `=` or `,`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The braces are needed so that the parser can treat some group as a single element and avoid parsing inside.

Consider the following:

```
\cmd[key=val=1,bla=0]
```

What should the parser understand? There are many possible meanings:

```
\cmd[key={val=1,bla=0}]
\cmd[key={val=1},bla=0]
\cmd[{key=val}=1,bla=0]
```

etc.

In some situations the particular interpretation the parser chooses can be invalid and generate an error.

Additionally, the call to `\cmd` itself is performing some parsing to understand for example if there is an optional argument or not; this requires escaping square brackets as well: writing `\cmd[key=\bla[1]]` will make `\cmd` think its optional argument is `key=\bla[1`.
To fix this, use `\cmd[key={\bla[1]}]`.

Also, as noted by @Joseph some keyval packages also strip spaces around the value so to include them you may need to put them in braces as well, or escape them in some way depending on the value:

```
\cmd[key={ val }] or \cmd[key=\ val\ ]
```

To sum up, in your examples the problematic characters are `]`, `,` and `=`, sometimes spaces too.

Comment: Depending on the parser, spaces at the start/end of the key and value are also stripped so like `key = { and }` may need the braces.

Comment: @JosephWright good catch I'll add that